# python 2, 3, os.environ and unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Can I write this to work with both python 2.x and 3.x, without explicitly testing for them?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function)

import os
import sys

if (sys.version_info[0] > 2):
  # python 3.x
  os.environ['foo'] = 'bár'
  print(os.environ['foo'])
else:
  # python 2.x
  os.environ['foo'] = 'bár'.encode('utf8')
  print(os.environ['foo'].decode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 5):

When *setting*, you could use exception handling; on Python 2 trying to set an environment variable to a `unicode` object raises an exception:

```
try:
    # Python 3
    os.environ['foo'] = 'bár'
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    # Python 2
    os.environ['foo'] = 'bár'.encode('utf8')
```

When getting, try to use the `decode` method; it'll fail in Python 3 with an attribute error:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    print(os.environ['foo'].decode('utf8'))
except AttributeError:
    # Python 3
    print(os.environ['foo'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In general I think Martijn's answer is the best answer, however if you're looking for an alternative for whatever reason, I used this with success for some time:

```
os.environ[key] = {
    type(''): lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'),  # Python 2
    str: lambda x: x,                       # Python 3
}.get(type(value), str)(value)
```

It's a bit tricky, but basically in python2 the dict will look like this:

```
{unicode: lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'),
 str: lambda x: x}
```

and in python3 it'll just look like this:

```
{str: lambda x: x}
```

This is because `type('')` in python3 is `str`, so the second `str` clobbers the first one. It then grabs the appropriate lambda from the dict to convert your value into the format needed by os.environ dict.

The advantage of this is that if you use coverage reporting tools, the dict counts as a single statement and both python2 and 3 will report 100% coverage even though one uses one lambda and the other uses the other. If you're not hyper-obsessed with having 100% code coverage like I am though, the try/except approach is much easier to understand generally, more pythonic and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** I think I may have misread your question. I thought your question involved not having to test for python versions each time you accessed `os.environ`. However, I believe may you mean how to check for python versions without explicitly looking at version information.

If on python 2 you could replace `os.environ` with your own dictionary that handles the encoding and decoding. Or as a more conservative approach you could create an object that encodes and decodes strings if necessary and then only access `os.environ` through this wrapper. eg.

**replacing os.environ**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function)

import os
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
  class _EnvironDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
      return super(_EnvironDict, self).__getitem__(key).decode("utf8")
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
      return super(_EnvironDict, self).__setitem__(key, value.encode("utf8"))

  os.environ = _EnvironDict(os.environ)

s = 'bár'
os.environ['foo'] = s
print(os.environ['foo'])
```

**A more conservative approach that doesn't replace** `os.environ`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function)

import os

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
  class _Environ(object):
    def __init__(self, environ):
      self.environ = environ
    def __getitem__(self, key):
      return self.environ[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
      self.environ[key] = value
else:  
  class _Environ(object):
    def __init__(self, environ):
      self.environ = environ
    def __getitem__(self, key):
      return self.environ[key].decode("utf8")
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
      self.environ[key] = value.encode("utf8")

environ = _Environ(os.environ)

s = 'bár'
environ['foo'] = s
print(environ['foo'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could [avoid the `unicode_literals` import if your code uses native string API heavily](http://python-future.org/imports.html#should-i-import-unicode-literals):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
import os

os.environ['foo'] = 'bar'
print(os.environ['foo'])
```

- as well as your code in the question, it fails in the default POSIX (C) locale on Linux with `UnicodeEncodeError` on Python 3 if the value is non-ascii (it is the locale that you might encounter while ssh-ing, in cron, init.d scripts, etc)
- it doesn't allow non-ascii literal values instead of failing to print these values if `sys.stdout.encoding` is not utf-8

To support arbitrary Unicode envvars, use Unicode API ([`_wenviron`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e30464040a38c7b038621768b7e9ba8a083ee702/Modules/posixmodule.c#L1150-L1180)) on Windows and [use bytes on POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635297/4279).

If you don't need to support arbitrary values and you are sure that all values are decodable by the current locale/`sys.stdout.encoding`/`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`:

```
import os
import sys

# values are representable in `sys.getfilesystemencoding() in this case
def os_encode(unicode_string, encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding()):
    return unicode_string.encode(encoding, 'strict')
def os_decode(bytestring, encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding()):
    return bytestring.decode(encoding, 'strict')

# bytestrings mapping (all values are decodable so it is ok to use bytes)
_environ = getattr(os, 'environb', os.environ) 
def setenv(key, value):
    _environ[os_encode(key)] = os_encode(value)
def getenv(key):
    return os_decode(_environ[os_encode(key)])
```

Then you can enable the `unicode_literals` import and use non-ascii characters in the string literals:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division, unicode_literals, absolute_import, print_function
import os

setenv('foo', 'bár')
print(getenv('foo'))
```