# python: getting actual environment variables to modify and pass to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, environment-variables

Well, it seems situation with environment variables is not consistent in python.

It's not a secret that reading environment variables using `os.environ` or `os.getenv` returns the state of env at the moment `os` module was imported. It's still possible to update environment using assignment to `os.environ` keys.

But once I used `os.putenv` or run any ctypes code that has modified the environment I get inconsistency between actual process environment and `os.environ`. Nuff said, this actual environment will be preserved for subprocess, no matter created with `os.system` or `subprocess` library. In my case it's desired behavior.

Now I want to review and change the environment passed to subprocesses. Usually it's suggested to get copy of `os.environ`, modify it and pass as a parameter to `subprocess.Popen` call. But in this case updates made to environment made by ctypes code will be lost.

Is there any way to overcome this issue? Strictly speaking is there a way to reload os.environ or get a copy with actual environment using other facilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`os.putenv()` does not update `os.environ` as [its docs say explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). C `putenv()` (in a CPython extension module) does not update `os.environ` too (as documented: changes in the environment after `os` import are not reflected in `os.environ`).

[`os.getenv(var)` is just `os.environ.get(var)`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e259c0ab7a69/Lib/os.py#l770-l774). There is [related Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1159) as [@ShadowRanger has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635933/4279).

If you need it; you could access [C environ](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08) from Python using `ctypes` e.g. (tested on Ubuntu, it might work on OS X (you might need to call [`_NSGetEnviron()` there](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/environ.7.html)), it is unlikely to work on Windows ([use `_wenviron` there)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e30464040a38c7b038621768b7e9ba8a083ee702/Modules/posixmodule.c#L1150-L1180)):

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
environ = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p).in_dll(libc, 'environ')
```

`environ` is a pointer to an array of C (NUL-terminated) strings (`char*`) where the last item is `NULL`. To enumerate values in Python 2:

```
for envvar in iter(iter(environ).next, None):
    print envvar
```

#### Output

```
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME=.project
SESSION=ubuntu
...
```

To get it as a dictionary that you could modify and pass to a child process:

```
env = dict(envvar.split(b'=', 1) for envvar in iter(iter(environ).next, None))
```

To synchronize with `os.environ`:

```
os.environ.clear() # NOTE: it clears C environ too!
getattr(os, 'environb', os.environ).update(env) # single source Python 2/3 compat.
```

Here're several convenience functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes
import functools
import os


_environ = None


def get_libc_environb_items():
    """Get envvars from C environ as bytestrings (unsplit on b'=')."""
    global _environ
    if _environ is None:
        libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
        _environ = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p).in_dll(libc, 'environ')
    return iter(functools.partial(next, iter(_environ)), None)


def get_libc_environb():
    """Get a copy of C environ as a key,value mapping of bytestrings."""
    return dict(k_v.split(b'=', 1) for k_v in get_libc_environb_items()
                if b'=' in k_v)  # like CPython



def get_libc_environ():
    """Get a copy of C environ as a key,value mapping of strings."""
    environb = get_libc_environb()
    # XXX sys.getfilesystemencoding()+'surrogateescape'
    fsdecode = getattr(os, 'fsdecode', None)
    if fsdecode is None:  # Python 2
        return environb  # keep bytestrings as is (`str` type)
    else:  # Python 3, decode to Unicode
        return {fsdecode(k): fsdecode(v) for k, v in environb.items()}


def synchronize_environ():
    """Synchronize os.environ with C environ."""
    libc_environ = get_libc_environ()
    os.environ.clear()
    os.environ.update(libc_environ)


def test():
    assert 'SPAM' not in os.environ
    assert 'SPAM' not in get_libc_environ()
    os.putenv('SPAM', 'egg')
    assert 'SPAM' not in os.environ
    assert os.getenv('SPAM') is None
    assert get_libc_environ()['SPAM'] == 'egg'
    assert os.popen('echo $SPAM').read().strip() == 'egg'
    synchronize_environ()
    assert os.environ['SPAM'] == 'egg'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(get_libc_environ())
```

It works on CPython 2, CPython 3, pypy. It doesn't work on Jython.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is this `environ` variable returned by `in_dll`.  It's diffrent from what `extern char **environ` is. See https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle/blob/master/src/spt_setup.c#L21 for examplec

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue with Python, as yet unfixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue1159). `os.getenv` reads from `os.environ`, and setting an item on `os.environ` implicitly does an `os.putenv`, deleting implicitly calls `os.unsetenv`, etc.

But even though `os.getenv` reads from `os.environ`, `os.putenv` doesn't write to it (and [this behavior is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.putenv)). And [there doesn't appear to be a way to make it reread the `os.environ`](https://bugs.python.org/issue463506). Basically, if you want a consistent environment, you have to update `os.environ` only, not use `os.putenv`; if `ctypes` calls are updating the C level `environ` directly, you're going to need another `ctypes` call to read the C level `environ` and update `os.environ` to match.